# Variable sql query depending on number of search parameter

Tags: php, sql

I need to do a sql query in php for search some entries (so using WHERE). But the field used to search could be of variable number.

I have a page with a search form, with 4 Field. It sends via `POST` the fields to a search.php that make a query:

```
$gomme_sql = $data->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE parameter1 = '$_POST['name1']' AND parameter2 = '$_POST['name2']' ORDER BY id ASC");
```

But I don't know which field are filled. So, if I don't enter anything in `field1` from the search form, I shouldn't have `parameter1 = '$_POST['name1']'` in the WHERE query.

Have you any idea how to obtain this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the post data before appending that clause to the query in a way like this:

edit: adding additional check:

```
$sql="select something from someTable ";
if(!empty($_POST['name1']) || !empty($_POST['name2'])) // add as many as you like
{
$sql.=" where ";
    if(!empty($_POST['name1']))
    {
        $sql.="parameter1= $_POST['name1']";
    }
// etc etc...
}
$sql.=" ORDER BY id ASC";
```

and so on.

Having said that, please, please use prepared statements with this sort of input from the user. This is SUPER open to sql injection. Please do read this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!
I'd like also, if no field is filled, that the page shows ALL the entries of the table. With that structure, in that case i have a WHERE without any argument passed...

Answer (score 0):

You can write generic sql select function like this , if you need more complex SQL just modify it.

```
    <?php


     function sqlSelect($table, $sel, $wh = '', $groupby = '', $order = '', $add = '') {

            $tb = $table;
            if (is_array($table)) {
                $tb = implode(',', $table);
            }
            if ($wh) {
                if (is_array($wh)) {
                    $w = array();
                    foreach ($wh as $k => $v) {
                        $v = mysqli_real_escape_string($v);
                        if (is_null($v))
                            $w [] = "$k=null ";
                        else
                            $w [] = "$k ='$v'";
                    }
                    $wh = 'where ' . implode(' and ', $w);
                }else {
                    $wh = "where $wh";
                }
            }
            if ($groupby)
                $groupby = "group by $groupby";
            if ($order)
                $order = "order by $order";
            $sql = "select $sel from $tb $wh $groupby $order $add ";
            return $sql;
        }
    //set _GET as this is console test    
    $_GET['name1']='Bob';
    $where = array(
        'name1'=>$_GET['name1']
    );
        echo sqlSelect('sometable' , '*' , $where) ."\n";
        // select * from sometable where name1 ='Bob'    

//or some complex stuff
        echo sqlSelect('persons', "age,status" , array('name'=>'Maria' , 'likes'=>'PHP') , null,  'age' , 'limit 20');
       //select age,status from persons where name ='Maria' and likes ='PHP'  order by age limit 20
```